# PHP SQL query doesnt return a result

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I have a button in a webapp that allows users to request a specially formatted number. When a user click this button 2 scripts run. The first that is fully functional, looks at a number table finds the largest number and increments it by 1. (This is not the Primary Key) the second script which is partially working gets the current date and runs a SQL query to get which period that date falls in. (Periods in this case not always equaling a full month) I know this script is at least partially working because I can access the $datetoday variable called in that script file. However it is not returning the requested data from the periods table. Anyone that could help me identify what I am doing wrong?

```
<?php
    include 'dbh.inc.php';
    $datetoday = date("Ymd");
    $sql = "SELECT p_num FROM periods where '$datetoday' BETWEEN p_start AND p_end";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        header("Location: ../quote.php?quotes=failed_to_write");
        exit();
    } else {
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $pnum = $row;
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
```

If it helps any one I published my code to https://github.com/cwilson-vts/Quote-Appliction

Comment: `BETWEEN p_start AND p_end` what is p_start/p_end here?

Comment: p_start is a column name in the periods table that lists the start of the period. p_end is a column name in the periods table thatis the end date of the period. p_num is the period number I am assigning to the dates in that range.

Comment: This condition is __incorrect__. `BETWEEN` is used when __field__ should have values between start and and.

Comment: It works when I query the database from phpmyadmin. So then the way around that would be something like :
    SELECT p_num from PERIODS
    where $datetoday > p_end AND $datetoday < p_start
?

Comment: If you change $sql to Select 1 from periods, does your script work fine?

Comment: @Bleach you mean for me to change my query to "SELECT 1 from PERIODS"
If so, then no that statement fails

Comment: What data type are `p_start` and `p_end`?

Comment: Then the problem is probably not your statement, but your connection. Your statement looks fine to me.

Comment: @Nick Both are date columns

Comment: @Bleach I am using the same connection file dbh.inc.php for this query and the one before it. And the one before it is incrementing the quote number as expected. This is also why I am so lost. I am not in anyway a developer of any sort, but the code looks solid. I just dont understand why it is not working

Comment: @u_mulder Do you have a direction you can point me in to make this work? Not to be rude but telling me im wrong and not at least pointing me in a direction is not very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what I was doing wrong, somebody with more PHP smarts than me will have to say for sure. In my above code I was using `mysqli_stmt_store_result` I believe that was clearing my variable before I intended. I changed that and reworked my query to be more simple.

```
    <?php
include 'dbh.inc.php';
$datetoday = date("Ymd");
$sql = "SELECT p_num FROM periods WHERE p_start <= $datetoday order by p_num desc limit 1";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    header("Location: ../quote.php?quotes=failed_to_write");
    exit();
} else {
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $pnum = $row['p_num'];
    echo $pnum;
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

Thanks to @rhuntington and @nick for trying to help. Sorry I am such an idiot.

Comment: Not an idiot man. Glad you found what you were looking for. Looming over your query, that makes sense. I didn't understand what it is you were attempting. As for the printing of the array, remember that was only a testing method to show what results you get. You would of course print the array in a nice and neat fashion for your site. Glad you figured it out! Just remember everyone starts somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

So first off, I do not use msqli and never learned it. However, I believe I get the gist of what you want to do. I use PDO because I FEEL that it is easier to use, easier to read and it's also what I learned starting off. It's kinda like Apple vs. Samsung... no one product is exactly wrong or right. And each have their advantages and disadvantages. What I'm about to provide you will be in PDO form so I hope that you will be able to use this. And if you can't then no worries.

I want to first address one major thing that I saw and that is you interlacing variables directly into a mysql statement. This is not considered standard practice and is not safe due to sql injections. For reference, I would like you to read these sites:

http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Next, I'm noticing you're using `datetime` as a variable name. I advise against this as this is reserved in most programming languages and can be tricky. So instead, I am going to change it something that won't be sensitive to it such as `$now = "hello world data";`

Also I'm not seeing where you would print the result? Or did you just not include that?
Another thing to consider: is your datetime variable the same format as what you are storing in your db? Because if not, you will return 0 results every time. Also make sure it is the right time zone too. Because that will really screw with you. And I will show you that in the code below too.

So now on to the actual code! I will be providing you with everything from the db connection code to the sql execution.

DB CONNECTION FILE:

```
<?php

    $host = '127.0.0.1';
    $user = 'root';
    $pw = '';
    $db = 'test'; // your db name here (replace 'test' with whatever your db name is)

    try {
        // this is the variable will call on later in the main file
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;", $user, $pw);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        // kills the page and returns mysql error
        die("Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage());
    }
?>
```

The data file:

```
<?php
    // calls on the db connection file
    require 'dbconfig.php';

    // set default date (can be whatever you need compared to your web server's timezone). For this example we will assume the web server is operating on EST.
    date_default_timezone('US/Eastern');
    $now = date("Ymd");

    // check that the $now var is set
    if(isset($now)) {
        $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT p_num FROM periods WHERE p_start BETWEEN p_start AND :now AND p_end BETWEEN p_end AND :now");
        $query->bindValue(':now', $now);
        if($query->execute()) {
            $data = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            print_r($data); // checking that data is successfully being retrieved (only a troubleshooting method...you would remove this once you confirm it works)
        } else {
            // redirect as needed and print a user message
            die("Something went wrong!");
        }
        $query->closeCursor();
    }
?>
```

Another thing I want to mention is that make sure you follow due process with troubleshooting. If it's not working and I'm not getting any errors, I usually start at the querying level first. I check to make sure my query is executing properly. To do that, I go into my db and execute it manually. If that's working, then I want to check that I am actually receiving a value to the variable I'm declaring. As you can see, I check to make sure the `$now` variable is set. If it's not, that block of code won't even run. PHP can be rather tricky and finicky about this so make sure you check that. If you aren't sure what the variable is being set too, echo or print it with simply doing `echo $now`

If you have further questions please let me know. I hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks @rhuntington! I will give this a shot and let you know.

Comment: This does something but it doesn't do what it needs to. It returns "Array" and not the value of p_num in the array.
When I run your query in SQL replacing :now with 20181001 I get p_num 01-09 listed out, but not the actual p_num today would be in \which is 10.

Comment: Okay would you please copy here what it's exactly printing out and then would please tell what the type of data is in p_start and p_end. Is it a timestamp? Or a varchar? I can't help without knowing what the data types are in the db.

Comment: This is the output: Array ( [0] => Array ( [p_num] => 01 ) [1] => Array ( [p_num] => 02 ) [2] => Array ( [p_num] => 03 ) [3] => Array ( [p_num] => 04 ) [4] => Array ( [p_num] => 05 ) [5] => Array ( [p_num] => 06 ) [6] => Array ( [p_num] => 07 ) [7] => Array ( [p_num] => 08 ) [8] => Array ( [p_num] => 09 ) )

Comment: And I am using the date data type

Comment: Ah I think I see the issue. I forgot to add dashes to the date format in PHP. Is your database date format this? YYYY-MM-DD? Without the time? Correct?

Comment: So looking back at your original post, you want to take the current day and find numbers with the dates that fall in between the current date?

Comment: That is correct. The query listed in my post runs in the database and returns the result I need. But once I have coded it into the website it doesn't work. I was thinking maybe I dont have enough connections to be open at one time? I am really just lost.

Comment: I played around some more last night and found I just need to modify my query. so my query is now `"SELECT MAX(p_num) FROM periods WHERE p_start <= :now"` And it returns `Array ( [0] => Array ( [MAX(p_num)] => 10 ) )` Now I just need to strip everything else away. because all that is coming over is the "Array" word